# Conda environment not working after activation

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu

I have installed anaconda3 on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS , I have created multiple environments on anaconda

my normal python version is 3.5.2 so when I do

```
python --version
```

I get

```
Python 3.5.2
```

when I activate my conda environment pycoin I get

```
flying_raijin@Titan:~$ source activate pycoin
(pycoin) flying_raijin@Titan:~$
```

which is what is supposed to be 
In this env - pycoin I have python version to be 3.6.8 also I have several new  libraries installed 
But I cant seem to access any of these libraries as well as I get version as 3.5.2 which should be 3.6.8 in pycoin
so when i do

```
(pycoin) flying_raijin@Titan:~$ python --version
```

I get

```
Python 3.5.2
```

Which should be 3.6.8

When I go to anaconda-navigator and then run this pycoin env manually it works as it is supposed to by showing python --version to be 3.6.8 and all libraries installed

but using source activate pycoin doesnt work

Please help!!!

Comment: How did you create pycoin  environment?

Comment: I created it using anaconda-navigator ..with anaconda-navigator it works well but its like ..every time I want to use conda environment I gotta run anaconda-navigator first and then I have to run a terminal of specific environment

Comment: Does 'conda activate pycoin' work?